# How to produce this example environment?

Tags: color, mdframed

Please, I want to produce this environment of example with the same colors

[image]

Any ideas please? Thanks.

Comment: Use `tcolorbox` and `amsmath` packages. Done.

Comment: @Too Fat Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

As @Too Fat suggested, here is what I found with `tcolorbox`

```
\begin{tcolorbox}
   [arc=0mm,outer arc=0mm,
   boxrule=0mm,toprule=0.5mm,bottomrule=0.5mm,left=0mm,right=0mm,leftrule=0pt,
   titlerule=0mm,toptitle=0mm,bottomtitle=0mm,top=0mm,
   colframe=gray!50,colback=green!5!white,coltitle=blue!50!black]
  \textcolor{blue}{\textbf{EXEMPLE 1}}\\
 Some texts .....
\end{tcolorbox}
```

which give

[image]

Thank you all.

Comment: There is a typo on: EX(E)MPLE....after very good for your work.

Comment: Sorry! It's "Example" of course.